# Launch camera on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, camera, gallery

I'm working on a app where I have to launch the camera. In Jelly Bean the gallery and camera merged and are now the same app (`com.android.gallery3d` I think). I've been searching for a answer on how to launch the camera but they're all about the `startActivityForResult()` method. I don't want the user to return to my app and I don't want my app to get the photo.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Intent works fine for me on JellyBean:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
startActivity(intent);
```